# mysql join : get all rows that matches the rows that matches notification type is zero

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in my database

1.mir_notifications 
(id(PK),title,message,notifcaton_type)

2.mir_users_notifications
 (id,user_id,notif_id(FK))

`notif_id` refers to `id` in the `mir_notification` table

I want to fecth all rows from `mir_notification` table that matches a user_id  in `mir_users_notifcations` table and `notification_type` in `mir_notifications` table along with all  rows that has `notifcation_type` is `0`

(ie **if notifcation type is zero it will fetch for all users**)

Here is the query i  am used

```
SELECT mir_notifications.* FROM mir_notifications LEFT JOIN mir_users_notification ON mir_notifications.id=mir_users_notification.notif_id WHERE mir_notifications.notfication_type IN (0,2) AND  mir_users_notification.user_id=2
```

Here i am passing notification type 0  and 1 and userid is 2 ,currently this user have no special notification but he have a common notification (ie notification_type is 0) so it should returs rows from `mir_notification` table that matches `notification_type` is zero but it will returns empty results

Comment: Consider providing proper CREATE and INSERT statements together with a desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply modify your `WHERE` clause. The query below will get all notifications of type `2` for user `2`, along with all notifications of type `0`.

`SELECT mir_notifications.* FROM mir_notifications LEFT JOIN mir_users_notification ON mir_notifications.id=mir_users_notification.notif_id WHERE (mir_notifications.notfication_type = 2 AND mir_users_notification.user_id=2) OR (mir_notifications.notification_type = 0)`

Comment: its worked thanks bro:) +1 for understnding my actual needs